# How to exclude a WinForms control from auto-scaling?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, user-controls, scaling

i have a `UserControl` which contains a `TextBox`.

When my parent `UserControl` is resized, the internal `TextBox` is carefully respositioned.

If the `UserControl` is resized due to form's AutoScaling, then my `UserControl` is scaled (as it should be). But then my child `TextBox` is resized out from under me.

How can i have my owned `TextBox` exclude itself from scaling?

The mechanism works in such a way that i can't "patch it up afterwards"; which is fortunate, because i don't want to resort to such an ugly hack (i.e. i want the proper solution).

---

i tried *not* calling `base.ScaleControl`:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
   protected override void ScaleControl(SizeF factor, BoundsSpecified specified)
   {
      //base.ScaleControl(factor, specified);
      UpdateTextBoxPosition();
   }
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: You'll have to allow it to rescale or it won't fit the font.  Simply put it where you want it in OnLoad().

Comment: @HansPassant i'll be taking care of the font myself - WinForms doesn't handle font scaling properly anyway (if the isn't left at the default font: it ignores cascading font changes). And i can't let the `TextBox` scale itself due to rounding errors between the container and where the `TextBox` needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track, but the wrong control.

Try inheriting your own TextBox to ignore those changes:

```
public class UnscaledTextBox : TextBox {

  protected override void OnParentFontChanged(EventArgs e) {
    //base.OnParentFontChanged(e);
  }

  protected override void ScaleControl(SizeF factor, BoundsSpecified specified) {
    //base.ScaleControl(factor, specified);
  }
}
```

Use the `UnscaledTextBox` control in your UserControl and see if that does the trick.

Comment: i can't inherit from `TextBox`; the `TextBox` is just one control in my `UserControl`.

Comment: @IanBoyd Why couldn't you just replace the TextBox in the UserControl with this one?  They're the same control, this one just ignores the scaling and font changes coming from the parent.

Comment: i see what you're saying - create an entire set of custom controls simply so that they ignore scaling. *ugh* i hope there's a better way.

Comment: @IanBoyd Yes and no.  I agree that would be a lot of work if you had to do it for a bunch of controls, but your question *was* about *one* TextBox, so that's all I focused on.

Comment: That's the danger is providing an example with a question. Normally i try to post multiple examples so people don't get bogged down in the example.